# how pytorch nn.module save submodule

Tags: python, pytorch

I have some question about how pytorch nn.module works

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn



class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        self.sub_module = nn.Linear(10, 5)
        self.value = 3

net = Net()
print(net.__dict__)
```

output

```
{'_modules': OrderedDict([('sub_module', Linear (10 -> 5))]),  'value': 3, ...}
```

I know that every attribute of a class should be stored in **__dict__**, why value(a int value) is in it, but sub_module(a nn.Module) is not, instead, sub_module is stored in **_modules**

I read the code of nn.Module implementation, but I didn't figure that out. do anyone have any ideas?

thank you !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to keep it simple.

Every time you create a new item in the class `Net` for instance: `self.sub_module = nn.Linear(10, 5)` it calls the method `__setattr__` of its parent class, in this case `nn.Module`. Then, inside `__setattr__` method, the parameters are stored to the dict they belong. In this case since `nn.Linear` is a module, it is stored to the `_modules` dict.

Here is the piece of code that does this inside the `Module` class  https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py#L389