# How can I have submodules of a PyTorch Module that are not attributes of the module

Tags: python, pytorch

I would like to have a PyTorch sub-class of `Module` that keeps sub-modules in a list (because there may be a variable number of sub-modules depending on the constructor's arguments). I set this list in the following way:

```
self.hidden_layers = [torch.nn.Linear(i, o) for i, o in pairwise(self.layer_sizes)]
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54994658/how-does-pytorchs-nn-module-register-submodule) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47324354/how-pytorch-nn-module-save-submodule) question, a submodule is only registered by `__setattr__`, when a `Module` object is assigned to an attribute of `self`. Because `hidden_layers` is not assigned an object of type `Module`, the submodules in the list are not registered as submodules, and as a result `self.parameters()` does not iterate over the submodules' parameters.

I suppose I could explicitly call `__subattr__` for each element of the list but that would be quite ugly. Is there a more correct way to register a submodule that is not a direct attribute of `Module`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As answered `nn.ModuleList` is what you want.

What you can also use is `nn.Sequential`. You can create a list of layers and then combine them via `nn.Sequential`, which will just act as a wrapper and combines all layers to essential one layer/module. This has the advantage that you only need one call to forward it through all the layers, which is nice if you have a dynamic count of modules, so you don't have to write the loops on your own.

One example would be in the pytorch ResNet code: https://github.com/pytorch/vision/blob/497744b9d510ff2df756f479ee5a19fce0d579b6/torchvision/models/resnet.py#L177

Answer (score 4):

Use `nn.ModuleList`.

```py
self.hidden_layers = nn.ModuleList([torch.nn.Linear(i, o) for i, o in pairwise(self.layer_sizes)])
```